# Executemso error after using it to post a chart from excel to ppt

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm current using vba to automate the creation of a ppt report. I need to copy charts from excel and paste into ppt. I successfully used the ExecuteMso "PasteExcelChartSourceFormatting" to paste the chart in, which I need to use so I can paste while keeping the source formatting and embedding the workbook, but I keep getting an error after that when my code tries to reposition the chart in ppt. 
See code:

```
Sub Update()

    Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide


    Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application

    ppApp.Visible = True
    ppApp.Activate

    Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\ashah\Documents\Advisory.pptx")

    ppPres.Slides(1).Shapes(7).Delete
    Sheet1.ChartObjects("Chart 24").Chart.ChartArea.Copy
    ppPres.Slides(1).Select
    DoEvents

    ppApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelChartSourceFormatting"
    ppApp.CommandBars.ReleaseFocus
    DoEvents

    ppPres.Slides(1).Shapes(7).Left = _
      (ppPres.PageSetup.SlideWidth / 2) - (ppPres.Slides(1).Shapes(7).Width / 2)
    ppPres.Slides(1).Shapes(7).Top = 77

End Sub
```

I get a run-time error '--2147188160 (80048240)', method 'Item' of object 'Shapes' failed. The debug highlights the last few lines of my code.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure `Shape(7)` exists?

Comment: I believe so, as when I used a standard paste code like ppPres.Slides.Shapes.Paste, then the position code works. It's just not working with executeMso

Comment: Even if I change the last 2 lines of the code to Shape(1) or any figure, it doesnt work. These shapes do exist in the powerpoint!

Comment: I hate using ExecuteMso. It takes way longer than it should, so that DoEvents (even a dozen DoEvents!) doesn't let the object be created in time for the subsequent code to act on that object. In [another post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37063056/485674) I proposed a lame little loop that keeps checking whether the shape is ready to be moved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this, slightly different method

```
Sub Update()
    Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

    Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application

    ppApp.Visible = True
    ppApp.Activate

    Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\ashah\Documents\Advisory.pptx")
    Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides(1)
    ppSlide.Shapes(7).Delete

    Sheet1.ChartObjects(1).Chart.ChartArea.Copy

    ppSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select

    With ppPres.Windows(1).Selection.ShapeRange
        .Left = (ppPres.PageSetup.SlideWidth / 2) - (.Width / 2)
        .Top = 77
    End With

End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**
I split this into two subs. Can you give this a try

```
Sub Update()
    Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

    Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application

    ppApp.Visible = True
    ppApp.Activate

    Set ppPres = ppApp.presentations.Open("C:\Users\ashah\Documents\Advisory.pptx")
    Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides(1)
    ppSlide.Shapes(7).Delete

    Call CopyAndPasteChart(ppApp, ppSlide)

    With ppSlide.Shapes(ppSlide.Shapes.Count)
       .Left = (ppPres.PageSetup.SlideWidth / 2) - (.Width / 2)
       .Top = -77
    End With
    ppApp.CommandBars.ReleaseFocus

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub CopyAndPasteChart(ppApp As PowerPoint.Application, ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide)
    Sheet1.ChartObjects(1).Chart.ChartArea.Copy
    ppApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteExcelChartSourceFormatting")
End Sub
```

You could edit the `CopyAndPasteChart` Sub a bit more if you fancied to make it usable in more situations.

Comment: Thanks this does work to an extent, however as I said, I need to use executeMso "PasteExcelChartSourceFormatting" to replicate the action of paste special, keep source formatting and embed workbook

Comment: The error does seem to arise after using executeMso - which although pastes the chart in, seems to make the macro encounter errors for any subsequent code. I'm not sure if this is a common problem or not?

Comment: I've just found that as well. It seems the executeMso doesn't complete until the sub has finished. Therefore the last part of the sub can't execute correctly. If you're updating this from Excel using a routine, could you not paste this as an image instead of a chart object?

Comment: Is there a work around for that? Unfortuantely I need the presentation in that way so I can use the pasted embedded workbook

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little late to the game, but I used this post to try and answer the same problem I was having. And I wanted to pay it forward when I found the solution.

Now my code is a little different because I'm creating a new slide for every chart in my excel worksheet, but I too need to keep the source formatting.

```
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim CurrentSlide As Object
Dim PowerPointDoc As Object
Dim xChart As ChartObject
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Chart As ChartObject
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim x As Long

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
Set PowerPointDoc = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add(msoTrue)
PowerPointApp.Visible = True

For Each Chart In ws.ChartObjects
    PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add 
    PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.count + 1, 12
    Set CurrentSlide = PowerPointDoc.Slides(PowerPointDoc.Slides.count)
    CurrentSlide.Select
    Chart.Copy
    PowerPointApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelChartSourceFormatting"

    '**********************************
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until CurrentSlide.Shapes.count > 0
    '**********************************

Next Chart
```

The "Do While Loop" has helped avoid this error. It does take some time for the macro to finish depending on how many charts you have.

Comment: This is a great solution to the above issue!