# Procedure continues before chart has been pasted from Excel to Powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

On occasion you will want to copy a chart in Excel and paste it into a PowerPoint presentation using VBA. This comes in handy when you want to automate a report.

**Problem:** assuming you are not converting the graph to an image, and depending on the size and complexity of the graph you are trying to paste, the graph does not have time to paste before VBA attempts to continue with the procedure. This is annoying when you want to manipulate the graph after it has been pasted (e.g. positioning it on the slide). What effectively happens is you end up trying to move a chart on the slide... that does not yet 'exist' as a PowerPoint shape.

This issue is annoying and in my humble opinion actually constitutes a bug. I have not yet seen a robust solution to the problem on SO, with the potential exception of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37060831/using-vba-to-paste-excel-chart-with-data-into-powerpoint) from John Peltier. His answer is most likely correct (and has been designated as such on the thread) but unfortunately I could not get this to work in my implementation.

The issue I lay out below.

**Code (simplified for ease of reference):**

```
   Public Sub X2P()           
       'Copy chart and paste
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
        Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(2)    
        PasteChartIntoSlide mySlide    
    End Sub

    Function PasteChartIntoSlide(theSlide As Object) As Object    
        CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application").CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")            
    End Function
```

Comment: It can't be a bug as programs don't use the clipboard. Users do, _The clipboard is user-driven. A window should transfer data to or from the clipboard only in response to a command from the user. A window must not use the clipboard to transfer data without the user's knowledge._ From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/about-the-clipboard

Comment: Am suggesting this could be a bug because the procedure is not waiting for the command to be completed before resuming, Nowhere am I suggesting this isn't a user-initiated command.

Comment: @Mark see the code? It says `.Copy`, so the VBA is using the clipboard. So VBA is working as a user, or as the user's delegate. And the thing is, it's the only way to get those charts to PowerPoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see others have tried to break up the script and to copy, paste and position charts using separate functions. This is cleaner, but it has not worked for me.

The solution I have found is to count the number of shapes on the slide before the code pastes the chart, `num_obj`, and to set variable `num_obj_final` as `num_obj + 1` (i.e. total number of shapes once the chart has been pasted). I then create a loop after the paste event, where I recalculate `num_obj` with every iteration. Only when `num_obj` is equal to `num_obj_final` does the procedure exit the loop. And then the script can resume as expected, as you can be sure that the shape now 'exists' on the slide.

**Final code for PasteChartIntoSlide() function:**

```
Function PasteChartIntoSlide(theSlide As Object) As Object
    theSlide.Select

    num_obj = 0
    num_obj_final = theSlide.Shapes.Count + 1
    CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application").CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")

    DoEvents

    Do Until num_obj = num_obj_final
    num_obj = theSlide.Shapes.Count
    'Debug.Print num_obj
    Loop

End Function
```

Comment: As a guy who breaks it into separate procedures to force the copy to finish before the paste starts, and finish the paste before subsequent manipulation of the pasted object, Bravo! Whatever you need to do to make the code keep in sequence. I've tried a few loops, and yours looks as effective as any I've tried.