# Have trouble to understand why this code fails

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Have been working on this problem for days and cant figure it out. On line with ExecuteMso I get following error message Method "ExecuteMso" of object "_CommandBars" failed. I'm having difficulty to understand or find why.

Searched web for days.

```
Sub GenerateReport()
Dim Wapp As Object
    'Launches word application
    Set Wapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Wapp.Visible = True
    Wapp.Activate
...
   Call CreateChart(Wapp)
End Sub

'Procedure, chart in word
Sub CreateChart(Wapp As Object)
Dim FomtCh As Excel.ChartObject
Dim InlineShCount As Long
    'Create reference to excel chart
    Set FomtCh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Doc").ChartObjects(1)
    'Copy from excel chart to word chart
    FomtCh.Chart.ChartArea.Copy
    'Counts number of shapes in word document
    InlineShCount = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count
    'Paste without linking to excel chart and embeding copy in word file
    Word.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteExcelChartSourceFormatting")
    Do '<~~ wait completion of paste operation
        DoEvents
    Loop Until ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count > InlineShCount
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI, `Word.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteExcelChartSourceFormatting")` does not need parenthesis, and it can even create errors in some cases (probably not here thought). Either keep the parenthesis and use `Call`, or remove them, excepted if you understand what is the effect of using them. (Hint: If the VBE add a space before the `(`, you probably don't need them.)

Comment: People [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36692962/executemso-error-after-using-it-to-post-a-chart-from-excel-to-ppt) have found out that "ExecuteMso doesn't complete until the sub has finished. Therefore the last part of the sub can't execute correctly." The solution was to outsource that command to another Sub.

Comment: ok I changed line to Word.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelChartSourceFormatting" and deleted all code after it, and it still gives same error.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Wapp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso` instead of `Word.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso`, as that is your Word object?

Comment: Those lines are equal. Error is same if I use Wapp or Word.Application in beginning.

Comment: Do you have the reference to the Word object library enabled? [VBA-Tools-References](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-object-libraries-to-your-visual-basic-project-ed28a713-5401-41b0-90ed-b368f9ae2513)

Comment: From where did you get "PasteExcelChartSourceFormatting"? If this command doesn't exsist as a *built-in* RibbonX control, it's cannot be use with `ExecuteMso`. At a quick glance, I don't see it in the list of commands in Word's "Customize Ribbon" dialog box...

Comment: @CindyMeister the 4 paste chart commands aren't on the ribbon but can be added to the QAT. Set "Choose commands from" to "All Commands" and look for "Paste Chart with". FWIW when i tested it (O365) I didn't get the results the OP wants.

Comment: I have following libraries enabled for project: Visual Basic For Applications, Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library, OLE Automation, Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library and Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library, I got idea about ExecuteMso from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185788/how-to-copy-a-chart-from-excel-to-powerpoint/19187572#19187572 and assumed that it would be pretty similar for word, as I could not find any information how to do something similar for word.

Answer (score -1):

Not all of the Ribbon commands exist in the legacy CommandBars collection.

To get a full listing of the available commands create a blank document in Word and run the code below (from Word).

```
Sub ListCommands()
  Dim cbar As CommandBar
  Dim cbarCtrl As CommandBarControl

  For Each cbar In Application.CommandBars
    For Each cbarCtrl In cbar.Controls
      Selection.TypeText cbarCtrl.Caption & vbCr
    Next cbarCtrl
  Next cbar

End Sub
```